# Who was the man in the cave, Oliver left behind?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, arrow

In Season 1 Episode 15 of *Arrow*, Oliver Queen is having a flashback where he sees someone who claims to be a student...He leaves him, though it is heavily implied that he's trap.

Is this person's identity, or even just fate ever revealed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. He is later revealed to be

> [a spy for Fyers](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Alan_Durand)

He shows up again when

> Oliver finds him working as a radio/communications tech.

His final fate

> comes at the hands of Shado, who snaps his neck.

Note: I don't recall him ever being named in the show, but Wiki identifies him by name.